# How to add single quotation marks in the rename command to change the file name?

Tags: command-line, rename

I am renaming a text file from `Programmer.txt` to `Programmer's File.txt` using the rename command in the terminal. I tried the following command:

```
rename 's/Programmer/Programmer's\ File' *.txt
```

But it isn't working. I guess the single quotation mark in the word `Programmer's` is the problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Since single quotes are not special when inside double quotes, the simplest way is

```
rename -n "s/Programmer/Programmer's File/" *.txt
```

(note that the space character does not need to be escaped, since the quotes already protect it from expansion by the shell).

Alternatively, close the quote, pass an escaped quote `\'` to the shell, then open the quotes again:

```
rename -n 's/Programmer/Programmer'\''s File/' *.txt
```

or you could forgo the quoting altogether and just escape the shell-special characters directly:

```
rename -n s/Programmer/Programmer\'s\ File/ *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an escape character:

`sudo mv Programmer.txt "Programmer\'s File.txt"`

Escape characters preserve the following character so that Bash or any other program doesn't interpret it in any other way apart from literal.

Comment: How can I do the same thing with the remove command?

Comment: @SayakChina Remove is different, You don't need to escape quotes with remove. It is `sudo rm "Programmer's File.txt"` if that is the file you are trying to delete?

Edit: To be honest, escape quotes are not even needed to begin with if you just specify paths and files surrounded by quotation marks...